# Required: T Chisel Error

Tags: chisel

I get the following chisel errors for `io.out(i) := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)` line. What does it mean? and how do I rectify this? Please help.

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.core.UInt
[error]  required: T
[error]     io.out(i) := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)

type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.core.Vec[chisel3.core.UInt]
[error]  required: T
[error]     io.out(i) := Cat(io.in1(0) ,io.in2)
```

Comment: Can you share the source, since the return type of Cat is UInt it is likely that the type of io.out is different and a cast of some sort is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chick mentioned, we really need to see more context but I think I have enough to glean what is going on. One part of the error message that I suspect you left off is:

```
[error] inferred type arguments [chisel3.core.Data] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.Bits]
[error]   io.out(i) := Cat(io.in1(0), io.in2)
[error]
```

What this says is that the type of the arguments to `Cat` must be a subtype of `chisel3.Bits`. `Vec` is not a subtype of `Bits`, so you cannot pass a `Vec` to `Cat`.

It would be helpful to have more information about what you're trying to do to give better advice, but if you're trying to construct a `UInt` that is the concatenation of a `UInt` and a `Vec`, you can convert the `Vec` to a UInt by calling `.asUInt`, eg. `Cat(io.in1(0), io.in2.asUInt)`. If you're trying to construct a larger `Vec` by prepending a `UInt` to it you can try `io.in1(0) +: io.in2`.